# Inspect Exchange items

Tags: powershell, exchange-2010

I would like to inspect mail and calendar items stored in an Exchange mailbox, by id, to see all their properties that are stored for them. Is there a way to do this (in powershell or the like)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Exchange Management Shell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297939(v=exchg.141).aspx).  In particular, there are powershell cmdlets that provide access to exchange objects.  This should provide what you need.